# Using PySpark Imputer on grouped data

Tags: pyspark, missing-data

I have a `Class` column which can be 1, 2 or 3, and another column `Age` with some missing data. I want to Impute the average `Age` of each `Class` group.

I want to do something along:

```
grouped_data = df.groupBy('Class')
imputer = Imputer(inputCols=['Age'], outputCols=['imputed_Age'])
imputer.fit(grouped_data)
```

Is there any workaround to that?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Imputer, you can filter down the dataset to each `Class` value, impute the mean, and then join them back, since you know ahead of time what the values can be:

```
subsets = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    imputer = Imputer(inputCols=['Age'], outputCols=['imputed_Age'])
    subset_df = df.filter(col('Class') == i)
    imputed_subset = imputer.fit(subset_df).transform(subset_df)
    subsets.append(imputed_subset)
# Union them together
# If you only have 3 just do it without a loop
imputed_df = subsets[0].unionByName(subsets[1]).unionByName(subsets[2])
```

If you don't know ahead of time what the values are, or if they're not easily iterable, you can groupBy, get the average values for each group as a DataFrame, and then coalesce join that back onto your original dataframe.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
averages = df.groupBy("Class").agg(F.avg("Age").alias("avgAge"))
df_with_avgs = df.join(averages, on="Class")
imputed_df = df_with_avgs.withColumn("imputedAge", F.coalesce("Age", "avgAge"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your dataframe with fitted model. Then take average of filled data:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

imputer = Imputer(inputCols=['Age'], outputCols=['imputed_Age'])
imp_model = imputer.fit(df)
transformed_df = imp_model.transform(df)
transformed_df \
    .groupBy('Class') \
    .agg(F.avg('Age'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not exactly what I wanted, by the way. What I need is to impute the mean of Age values when Class == 1 in missing values of Age when Class == 1, the mean of Age values when Class == 2 in missing values of Age when Class == 2, and the same when Class == 3.